# Como criar um select dinâmico para usar em localhost

Tags: php, javascript, html, localhost

Estou fazendo um sistema de comanda restaurante , mas tipo quero que o select seja dinâmico , tipo nem sempre o cliente quer uma comida apenas , então queria saber como posso fazer para ir adicionando toda vez que clico no mais . esse sistema só funciona no site , só que quero usar ele apenas no localhost e ele não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
código fonte abaixo.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <body>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
      <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
      <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
      <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
 <main>
      <form>
        <header>
          <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
        </header>
        <fieldset>
          <label>
           <span>Comanda:</span>
           <input type="text" value="" autofocus>
           </label>
            <label>
            <span>Mesa:</span>
            <input type="text" value="" autofocus>
          </label>
          <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
          <label>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <select id="selecionar">
            <option selected isabled>Selecione</option>
            <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
          <option  selected>Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
          <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
          <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
          <option  selected>Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
          <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
          <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
          <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
          <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
          <option  selected>Sardinha Frita</option>
          <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
          <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
          <option selected>Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
          <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
          <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
            </select>
            <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
            <hr>
            Selecionados
            <hr>
            <div id="selecionados">

            </div>
          </label>

          <label>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <select id="selecionar">
            <option selected isabled>Selecione</option> 
           <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
           <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
           <option selected>Cola Cola 1l</option>
           <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
          <option >Bare 2l</option> 
          <option  selected>Fanta Uva</option>
          <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
          <option >Sprit</option> 
          <option  selected>Cola Cola </option>
          <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
          <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
          <option  selected>Guaraná Baré</option>
          <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
          <option  selected>Suco Manga</option>
          <option >Suco Pessego</option>
          <option >Suco Uva</option> 
          <option  selected>Suco Maracujá</option>
          <option >Suco Laranja</option>
          <option >Suco Caju</option> 
          <option selected>Agua Mineral </option>
          <option >Agua com Gas </option>
          <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
          <option  selected>Limonada Natural</option>
            </select>
            <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
            <hr>
            Selecionados
            <hr>
            <div id="selecionados">

            </div>
          </label>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </main>
    <script>
            $(".add").on('click',function(){
        var cont=0;
        $("#selecionados input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==$("#selecionar option:selected").html()){
        cont++;
         }
        });
        if(cont>0){ alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");}
        else{
        $("#selecionados").append("<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='"+$("#selecionar option:selected").html()+"' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>");
        }
        });


    </script>

    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar uma `<select multiple>`? http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Olha o console do navegador, ve se aponta algum erro, porque ele deveria rodar em localhost

Comment: Boa tarde. Uma sugestão: você está colocando a tag `<script>` fora do `<html>` (pode ser por isto que está sendo ignorada). O melhor lugar para a tag `<script>` é geralmente ao final do `<body>`, que por acaso, você não tem. Sugiro estruturar melhor seu html com as tags corretas `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. Por fim, coloquei seu código em um fiddle e aparentemente está funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/8e9xLure/ .

Comment: já coloquei , mesmo assim não funciona em localhost . o código está como eu editei acima

Comment: Retira o css, da ultima linha la `.add{ text-decoration:none;}` essa, e adiciona na tag `<style>.add{ text-decoration:none;}</style>`

Comment: já o fiz coloquei ela em style aonde fico o códio css , mas em localhost ele não pega . mas quando testo online ele funciona .

Comment: olha o console do navegador, ve se aponta algum erro

Comment: sim em     border-sizing: border-box; aparece um sinal de alerta .

Comment: @allanaraujo continua com problemas de sintaxe. Você não fechou o `<head>` nem o `<html>`. E coloque a tag `<style>` dentro do head.   Checou o console por erros? você tem um servidor local ou está abrindo no arquivo?

Comment: Bem agora tá funcionando , mas está sobrepondo um sobre o outro e a parte das bebida só dar pra seleciona um quando vou seleciona outro ele dar que já foi adicionado . não fica como fica em site , coloquei um print acima de como fica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você estava usando a mesma função para a seleção das duas opçoes, e como estava com o mesmo id, ele dizia que ja estava selecionado. E realmente estava, mas não era o que você queria. Então uma forma simples de resolver foi renomear os ids e criar a outra função para o outro select.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Peixaria</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<style>
.add,add2{ text-decoration:none;}
#selecionados input,#selecionados2 input{ margin:10px;}
</style>
<h1>Peixaria</h1>
<ul class="menu cf">
  <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
  <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
  <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
</ul>
<main>
  <form>
    <header>
      <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
    </header>
    <fieldset>
      <label> <span>Comanda:</span>
        <input type="text" value="" autofocus>
      </label>
      <label> <span>Mesa:</span>
        <input type="text" value="" autofocus>
      </label>
      <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
      <label>
      <select id="selecionar">
        <option selected isabled>Selecione</option>
        <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
        <option  selected>Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
        <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
        <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option>
        <option  selected>Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
        <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
        <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
        <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
        <option >Tucunaré Frito</option>
        <option  selected>Sardinha Frita</option>
        <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
        <option >Pacu Frito</option>
        <option selected>Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
        <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
        <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
      </select>
      <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
      <hr>
      Selecionados
      <hr>
      <div id="selecionados"> </div>
      </label>
      <label>
      <select id="selecionar2">
        <option selected isabled>Selecione</option>
        <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option>
        <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option>
        <option selected>Cola Cola 1l</option>
        <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
        <option >Bare 2l</option>
        <option  selected>Fanta Uva</option>
        <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
        <option >Sprit</option>
        <option  selected>Cola Cola </option>
        <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
        <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option>
        <option  selected>Guaraná Baré</option>
        <option >Suco Goiaba</option>
        <option  selected>Suco Manga</option>
        <option >Suco Pessego</option>
        <option >Suco Uva</option>
        <option  selected>Suco Maracujá</option>
        <option >Suco Laranja</option>
        <option >Suco Caju</option>
        <option selected>Agua Mineral </option>
        <option >Agua com Gas </option>
        <option >Cerveja em Lata</option>
        <option  selected>Limonada Natural</option>
      </select>
      <a class="add2" href="#">+</a>
      <hr>
      Selecionados
      <hr>
      <div id="selecionados2"> </div>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>

<script>

            $(".add").on('click',function(){
        var cont=0;
        $("#selecionados input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==$("#selecionar option:selected").html()){
        cont++;
         }
        });
        if(cont>0){ alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");}
        else{
        $("#selecionados").append("<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='"+$("#selecionar option:selected").html()+"' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>");
        }
        });

  $(".add2").on('click',function(){
        var cont=0;
        $("#selecionados2 input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==$("#selecionar2 option:selected").html()){
        cont++;
         }
        });
        if(cont>0){ alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");}
        else{
        $("#selecionados2").append("<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='"+$("#selecionar2 option:selected").html()+"' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>");
        }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bem amigo ele ficou com o mesmo erro , tipo na hora de adiciona mais bebida ele dar que já tá adiciona sendo que nem tá . e eles ficam sobrepondo um sobre o outro

Comment: @allanaraujo, olha denovo, editei

Comment: bem a parte que só dar pra adicionar um ficou bem , mas eu tenho que mexe no formulário pra nenhum sobrepor sobre o outro ?tipo toda vez eu que adicionar uma refeição o select  da bebida sé empurrada pra baixo pra não sobrepor sobre ela ?

Comment: @allanaraujo como assim?

Comment: como na imagem que eu editei na pergunta acima , ela fica muito  perto da outra como posso dar um espaço entre eles pra ficar mais legíveis .Desde já agradeço.

Comment: @allanaraujo seria assim? adicionei la no css em cima

Comment: bem ele não funcionou e o espeça é entre o selecionado da refeição e o select do pedido de bebidas

Comment: @allanaraujo mas voce colocou como, da forma como coloquei ou anexou em algum arquivo css? Porque aqui rodou...

Comment: coloquei da maneira que editou. acho que é por quer é localhost ou não ?

Comment: Não... voce esta usando bootstrap? Provavelmente os estilos estao entrando em conflito, nesse caso coloque o `<style></style>` logo a cima do formulario

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51905/discussion-between-allan-araujo-and-localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu html e no seu javascript. Eis o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Peixaria</title>
    <style>
        .add {
            text - decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
        <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
    <main>
        <form>
            <header>
                <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
            </header>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <input type="text" value="">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Mesa:</span>
                    <input type="text" value="">
                </label>
                <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
                <div class="pedidos">

                    <select class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
                        <option  >Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
                        <option >Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
                        <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
                        <option >Sardinha Frita</option>
                        <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
                        <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
                        <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pedidos">

                    <select class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola 1l</option>
                        <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
                        <option >Bare 2l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Uva</option>
                        <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
                        <option >Sprit</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola </option>
                        <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
                        <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
                        <option >Guaraná Baré</option>
                        <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
                        <option >Suco Manga</option>
                        <option >Suco Pessego</option>
                        <option >Suco Uva</option> 
                        <option >Suco Maracujá</option>
                        <option >Suco Laranja</option>
                        <option >Suco Caju</option> 
                        <option >Agua Mineral </option>
                        <option >Agua com Gas </option>
                        <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
                        <option >Limonada Natural</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(".add").on('click',function(){ 

            var holder = $(this).closest('.pedidos');
            var selected_value = holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").val();
            var found = false;

            holder.find(".selecionados input").each(function(){
                if( $(this).val() === selected_value){
                    alert("Este item já esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais.");
                    found = true;
                }
            });

            if (found) return;

            var input1 = $("<input></input>", { 
                disabled: true,
                type: 'text',
                name: 'pedidos[]',
                value: selected_value
            });

            var input2 = $("<input></input>", {
                type: 'text',
                name: 'quantidade[]',
                placeholder: 'quantidade'
            });

            holder.find(".selecionados").append(input1, input2, "<br/>");

        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguns pontos:

- Código não estava corretamente indentado
- Você estava carregando duas vezes o `jQuery`.
- Você tinha muitos `autofocus` (você pode colocar apenas um por página);
- Adicionei um `<title></title>`.
- Muitos `<option>` com `selected` (é apenas um se
  o select não for múltipla escolha).
- Ao invés de `disabled`, você tinha escrito `isabled`.
- Substituí um `label` indevidamente usado por um `<div class='pedidos'>`
- Você tinha mais de um ID igual na página. Isso não pode. Você pode ter apenas um ID único por elemento. Desta forma, substituí seus `#selecionar` e `#selecionados` por uma classe e tratei no javascript para tratar cada campo (pedidos bebidas e  comidas) separadamente.
- **EDIT**: refatorei um pouco seu código JavaScript.

Depois destas modificações, testei aqui localmente e aparentemente está funcionando como você descreveu que deveria funcionar.

Comment: como eu poderia fazer pra por um espaço entre a refeição e a bebida pra não ficar muito junto e pra ficar mais legível .

Comment: @allanaraujo sugiro você fazer outra pergunta sobre estilo pois esta dúvida foge do escopo do que estamos tentando lhe ajudar. Primeiro, pesquise um pouco, tente implementar por você mesmo, e se, não conseguir, poste aqui sua pergunta específica com seu código, onde o erro aparece, o comportamento esperado etc.